# Start rendering a blend file from command-line WITH user interface

Tags: rendering, command-line

As the title says, I want to open a blend file from command-line (or rather with a batch file in Windows) and it should begin rendering the same way as if I pressed the *Render Animation Button*.

I have a batch file wich does all this in background:

```
d:\Programme\Blender\blender.exe -b %1 -a
```

But just omitting the -b option doesn't work. I tried:

```
d:\Programme\Blender\blender.exe %1 --render-anim
```

which opens Blender window and starts rendering, but it's just the main window with all inner content grey.

So is there a way to achieve this?